# Decode a JSON file with PHP

Tags: json

I have a classic JSON problem, and i know that many post are asking about that...
But i doubt that the JSON i try to grab has a correct structure.

The files Begin like that :

```
[{
"time":"0-12h",
"articles":[
{
"id":1,
"domain_id":22,
"title":"Hi Guys"
 }

{
"id":2,
"domain_id":17,
"title":"Hi everyone"
 }

]

}]
```

I have try a lot of combinaison to echo the title :

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
echo $data->articles;
```

Or

```
echo $data->articles->title;
```

Or

```
echo $data->articles[0]->title;
```

Nothing works... :(
Can you help me ?
Thanks !

Comment: If the file really looks like that, then it's invalid JSON. It's missing a comma between the `}` ending one object and the `{ starting the next in an array.

Comment: Invalid JSON to start with

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ: No, other than the missing comma, it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument `true` to `json_decode()` means it should create associative arrays rather than objects for `{}` in the JSON. So in addition to dealing with the indexed arrays as Explosion Pills points out, you also need to use array syntax to access the keyed elements:

```
$data[0]['articles'][0]['title']
```

If you want to be able to use `->` syntax, leave out the second argument or set it to `false`.

I'm hoping the missing comma in the JSON is an error when transcribing to the question. If not, you also need to fix the code that creates the JSON in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, it perfect ! You are right, the missing comma is my mistake. Many thanks for your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

`$data` itself is an array.  Try

```
$data[0]->articles[0]->title;
```

Also the JSON is not valid (missing a comma before the second articles array element).

Comment: As @Barmar mentionned in his answer, the second argument of the `json_decode` method creates an array, not an object.

Answer (score 0):

there is a `comma` ,  missing

```
}
,
{
```

`json_decode` with the second parameter `true` returns an array

```
print_r($data['articles']);
```

echo `$data['articles']` would output `Array`